# pyspark 2.3: how to evaluate GBTClassifier performance at each iteration?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Say I have a GBTClassifierMolel `gbm` with 100 iterations, I'd like to see how the model performs on a validation set by increasing iterations from 1 to 100. Currently, I'm doing something like:

```py
for index, model in enumerate(gbm.trees):
    pred = model.transform(X_valid)
    # then add the prediction to previous number 
    # to get the accumalted value at the current iteration
    ...
```

Problem is that it is very slow. Does anyone know how `GBTClaasifierMolel` can finish transforming with 100 trees fast? I could not locate the code, hope someone can point it out to me so I could customize it. Thanks!!

Comment: have you found the answer to this by any chance? @cjj